# iOS Take photo from camera problem

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios4

I've a problem with taking a photo with the iphone camera. I have following code:

```
- (IBAction)openCamera {
    UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    picker.delegate = self;
    [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
    [picker release];
}

- (IBAction)openCameraRoll {
    UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
    picker.delegate = self;
    [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
    [picker release];
}

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
    didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)image
              editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo
{

    UIImage *img = image;

    Image *imgHelp = [[Image alloc] init];


    UIImage *newImg =  [imgHelp imageByScalingProportionallyToSize:CGSizeMake(220, 220)     image:img];
    [self setImage:newImg];

    [[picker parentViewController] dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

- (void)setImage:(UIImage*)i {
    [imageBtn setImage:i forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

I found the problem. If I tested it with the debugger, i saw following:

If I take a photo from the camera roll it works fine. All references of self are available.
So the program can set the image.

But if I take a photo with the camera, all references of self (imageBtn p.e.) are not available, so the program cannot set the image.

What is my error?

Thanks for the answer

rob

Comment: you are setting the delegate picker.delegate = self; what is self (which kind of class obj)?

Comment: @interface ProfileCompletion01 : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIActionSheetDelegate,UIImagePickerControllerDelegate>

Comment: Can you please explain again of your statement "But if I take a photo with the camera, all references of self (imageBtn p.e.) are not available, so the program cannot set the image" **Image *imgHelp = [[Image alloc] init];** Is the **Image** custom class ? Where you are initializing imgButton, is it in reference to xib? If its in xib did you set the IBOutlet to xib?

Comment: The Image class is an extern class for resizing the images. It works fine. I set the image with the function setImage and the problem is that imageBtn is not available (0x0 in the debugger). The imgButton is part of a UITableViewCell referenced to the xib-file of the cell. But the reference is in this class, because this class the file owner of the tableviewcell

Comment: What is the file owner of your UITableViewCell nib file?

Comment: this class profilecompletion01

Comment: you must know, all works fine if i try it with the camera roll picker

Answer (score 0):

I do not know why you are overriding the setImage method of UIButton

you could have actually said

```
[self.imageBtn setImage:newImg forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

First of all your imageBtn is not available, Here your imageBtn initialized when you load the ProfileCompletion01 so are you releasing it somewhere? 
you can use the awakeFromNib method for your UItableViewCell to initialize the imageBtn again.

Comment: I try it with [additionalImage awakeFromNib] and with [imageBtn awakeFromNib] it doesn't work... I don't release the imageBtn. But why it works with the camera roll without a problem?